# Initiate pajinate() after ajax load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-pagination

Ok I'm not sure if it's the pajinate library that can't initiate after load() has completed since it works when I don't load() stuff in.

But I have to load views because I'm using Google Maps API. I list 3 per page. But I loop through the results I grab from AJAX and load a view into my current view:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
  // set keys with marker nodes to pass to view

  // load view file
  $( '#listings' ).append($('<div>').load( 'ajax/listingFind.php', {
      id: id, 
      name: name,
      logo: encodeURIComponent(logo),
      address: address,
      city: city,
      state: state,
      zip: zip,
      phone: phone,
      email: email,
      web_link: encodeURIComponent(web_link),
      distance: distance,
      marker: markerNum
    } ));
  createMarker(latlng, name, address);
  bounds.extend(latlng);
  fitToMarkers(bounds);
}
```

Yeah none of the other stuff is relevant. But I'm looping through my results and loading a view that grabs all that data into my current view.
THEN I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo __ASSET_PATH__ ?>/js/jquery.pajinate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
  $().ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#page_container').pajinate({
      nav_label_first : '',
      nav_label_last : '',
      nav_label_prev : '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>',
      nav_label_next : '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>',
      items_per_page : 3
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

So once the load() finishes, I try to execute pajinate. However, it doesn't execute and no errors are thrown in the console..
But when I manually put the loaded files in (which I can't do since I need to pass data for place information), it works fine.

Thanks for any additional help or.. if there are pagination plugins that can handle being called with an ajaxStop() function. I wouldn't think that would matter though.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out.

ajaxStop will not load if it's not attached to document.
This fixed it:

```
$(document).ajaxStop()
```

Along with getting rid of

```
$().ready()
```